# Bootstrap column align item as per space available in loop

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

The content is inside a div of md-8 and the content is in loop of PHP. The loop is:
 1. about us
 2. areas we cover
 3. job board
 4. candidates
 5. join us
 6. contact

Since the height of areas we cover is less, there is extra space at the bottom. I want the job board to fit there in extra space and same for candidate and join us.
How can I achieve this?

ANSWER : USE BOOTSTRAP CARD COLUMN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should put a main  to fit and group the item into one group so it could fit

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the extra space taken up is a margin or padding coming from the elements that contain the list.

`_reboot.scss` that comes with Bootstrap:

[image]

If using `dl`, `ol` or `ul` elements, remove the margin:

```css
dl, ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

If other elements used for creating the list, you can inspect them using the Browser's Developer Tools (Right-Click -> Inspect Element) and check what styles are applied. Once you know that, you can override them like I showed above.

Comment: its not margin .. its a height of every item being same and as a loop i cant give separate height for each item.

Comment: As long as they are not images, you can re-size, re-color every HTML element on the page using CSS. Can you please add to your question the markup of the rendered lists? I want to see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extra row and col inside of that col-md-8, 
like follow,

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- repeat the col-md-2 in 6 times as you need -->
        <div class="col-md-2"> 
           <!-- place the content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: it puts everything in column wise (side by side) ..but 3rd item doesnt stay on bottom of 2nd item and so for 5th and 4th item.